# React.js: How to determine the correct link?

Tags: css, reactjs, url, jsx

I need to output a list in which one of the elements is a picture. The link to the picture is different.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.contentKeys.length; i++) {
    let ingUrl = `../../img/data/${this.content[this.contentKeys[i]].imgMin}`
    ContentElements.push(
        <li key={i}>
            ...
            <div style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(ingUrl) + ')'}} ></div>
...
```

In this case, this does not work. Only the require(if the static path) or import works.

Import can not be used in a loop, the static path does not suit me.

How to solve my problem correctly?

Comment: Curious why not use absolute image paths?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './style.scss';
// import logo from '../../img/data/1-1.jpg';
// import img from '../../logo.svg';
// import dir from '../img/data/';


// console.log(img)

class Content extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.content = this.props.data
        this.contentKeys = Object.keys(this.content)
        this.renderContentElements = this.renderContentElements.bind(this)
    }

    renderContentElements(){
        this.contentKeys.map(key =>
            <li className="contentElement" key={i}>
                <div className="left">
                    <div className="realEstateType"><h2>{key.realEstateType}</h2></div>
                    <div className="floor"><h3>{key.floor} floor</h3></div>
                    <div className="bedrooms"><h3>{key.floor} bedrooms</h3></div>
                    <div className="price"><h2>${key.price}</h2></div>
                </div>
                <div className="center">
                    <div className="address"><h3>{key.address}</h3></div>
                    <div className="special"><h3>{key.special}</h3></div>
                    <div className="area"><h3>{key.area}</h3></div>
                </div>
                {/*background-image: url(http://i54.tinypic.com/4zuxif.jpg)*/}
                {/*<div className="right" style={{backgroundImage: "url(http://i54.tinypic.com/4zuxif.jpg)" }}></div>*/}
                <div className="right" style={{backgroundImage: `url(../../img/data/${key.imgMin}`}}></div>


                {/*<div className="right" style={{  backgroundImage: `url(${require('../../img/data/1-1.jpg')})` }} ></div>*/}
                {/*<div className="right" style={{  backgroundImage: 'url(' + require(String(ingUrl)) + ')' }} ></div>*/}

                {/*<img className={'test'} src={ingUrl} alt="Test" />*/}
                {/*<img className={'test'} src={require(ingUrl )}  alt="Test" />*/}

                {/*<img className={'test'} src={require(`${ingUrl}`)} />*/}


                       {/*<div className="right" style={{backgroundImage: require('../../img/data/1-1.jpg') }}></div>*/}
                {/*<img src={require('../../img/data/1-1.jpg')} alt=""/>*/}
                {/*<img className="test" src={'../../img/data/1-min.jpg'} alt=""/>*/}
                {/*<img className="test" src={logo} alt=""/>*/}
            </li>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul id="Content">
                {this.renderContentElements()}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Content;
```

You create an array of the contentKeys by using `Object.keys` for the content object.

Next, you iterate through each item of the array using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return an li element for each item, containing the relevant information.

Comment: Maybe I did not ask the question that way. @tay_thomp the links to the pictures are displayed correctly, there are no pictures on these paths. Rather, the point is that the path to become incorrect in the process of interpreting. On the screenshot I showed the right way. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OONwYO

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="right" style={{backgroundImage:  "url(" + require(`../../img/data/${this.content[i+1].imgMin}`) + ")" }}></div>
```